# ASP.NET Core: IsInRoleAsync and Authorize Attribute disagree

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am trying to implement basic authorization, but the Authorize attribute keeps rejecting my test admin account, even though IsInRoleAsync returns `true`. I'm pretty new to ASP.NET Core, so any help would be appreciated. This is building off of the ASP.NET Core Web App (MVC) template, if that helps. Below is what I believe to be the relevant code; please let me know if I can elaborate at all anywhere, or if I can improve this question otherwise. (I want to be as clear as possible!)

**ManageUsersController.cs** (with the attribute which rejects my admin account, stating "Access is Restricted")

```
[Authorize(Roles = Constants.AdministratorRole)] // Also tried (Policy = "RequireAdministratorRole"
public class ManageUsersController : Controller
{
    ....
}
```

**_AdminActionsParial.cshtml** (example snippet which returns `true` on if the account is an admin)

```
var isAdmin = currentUser != null
    && await userManager.IsInRoleAsync(
        currentUser,
        Constants.AdministratorRole);
```

**ConfigureServices within Startup.cs** (here is where I define the policy; I also included how I registered the services, in case I screwed that up at all)

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });

        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlite(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
        services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>()
            .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
            .AddRoleManager<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

        services.AddAuthorization(options => {
            options.AddPolicy("RequireAdministratorRole", policy => policy.RequireRole(Constants.AdministratorRole));
        });

        services.AddScoped<IToDoItemService, ToDoItemService>();
    }
```

**SeedData.cs** (this creates the test admin account)

```
public static class SeedData
{
    public static async Task InitializeAsync(
        IServiceProvider services) {
        var roleManager = services
            .GetRequiredService<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>();
        await EnsureRolesAsync(roleManager);

        var userManager = services
            .GetRequiredService<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>();
        await EnsureTestAdminAsync(userManager);
    }

    private static async Task EnsureRolesAsync(
        RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager) {
        var alreadyExists = await roleManager
            .RoleExistsAsync(Constants.AdministratorRole);

        if (alreadyExists) return;

        await roleManager.CreateAsync(
            new IdentityRole(Constants.AdministratorRole));
    }

    private static async Task EnsureTestAdminAsync(
        UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager) {
        var testAdmin = await userManager.Users
            .Where(x => x.UserName == "admin@todo.local")
            .SingleOrDefaultAsync();

        if (testAdmin != null) return;

        testAdmin = new ApplicationUser {
            UserName = "admin@todo.local",
            Email = "admin@todo.local"
        };

        await userManager.CreateAsync(
            testAdmin, "NotSecure123!!");

        await userManager.AddToRoleAsync(
            testAdmin, Constants.AdministratorRole);
    }
}
```

Again, any help would be appreciated, and please let me know if I need to provide more context anywhere.

Comment: `[Authorize]` is accessing `HttpContext.User` (ClaimsPrincipal) for roles and policy checks.  It has no knowledge of `UserManager`.